# Doctrine2 ManyToMany insert

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, many-to-many, insert-update

I'm using Zend Framework 2 with Doctrine2.
I have 2 entities with a many to many relationship: Project and User.
Doctrine created a table users_projects with fields project_id and user_id, because every project can have multiple users and each user can have multiple projects.
Now, when I add a project, I want to add multiple users to the project. 
So, how can I insert data in table users_projects?

**Project**

```
class Project {
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
* @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=TRUE)
*/
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="projects")
 */
protected $users;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

**User**

```
class User {
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
* @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=TRUE)
*/
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_projects")
 */
protected $projects;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->projects = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> So, how can I insert data in table users_projects?

You don't ;)

A quote from the documentation:

> A common mistake for beginners is to mistake DQL for being just some form of SQL and therefore trying to use table names and column names or join arbitrary tables together in a query. You need to think about DQL as a query language for your object model, not for your relational schema.

In your case you don't need to worry about the `users_projects` table, because you don't have an object (Entity) for it. You only have the `Project` and `User` entities, so you only have to attach these to each other. It's Doctrine's job to worry about the join-table.

Here's a good way to do this:

**Project**

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="projects")
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function addUser(User $user)
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users->add($user);
            $user->addProject($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function removeUser(User $user)
    {
        if ($this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users->removeElement($user);
            $user->removeProject($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return User[]
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users->toArray();
    }

    // ...
}
```

**User**

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_projects")
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $projects;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->projects = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param Project $project
     */
    public function addProject(Project $project)
    {
        if (!$this->projects->contains($project)) {
            $this->projects->add($project);
            $project->addUser($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Project $project
     */
    public function removeProject(Project $project)
    {
        if ($this->projects->contains($project)) {
            $this->projects->removeElement($project);
            $project->removeUser($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Project[]
     */
    public function getProjects()
    {
        return $this->projects->toArray();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Notice that `Project::getUsers()` and `User::getProjects()` don't return the collection itself, but a plain PHP array. This will make sure that the entities have *full control* over what's added/removed to/from those collections.

Secondly you'll see that `Project::addUser()` will not only add a User to its collection, but that User will also add that Project to its collection. This is important for bidirectional associations! Both sides need to be in agreement, otherwise strange things can (and will) happen.

This also goes for removing from the collection.

PS: The `contains()` check around adding/removing will make sure you'll *not* end up in an infinite loop ;)

**Working with this**

```
// user-table has 0 rows, project-table has 0 rows, join-table has 0 rows

$user = new User();
$project = new Project();

$em->persist($user);
$em->persist($project);

$em->flush();

// user-table has 1 row, project-table has 1 row, join-table has 0 rows

$project->addUser($user);

$em->flush();

// user-table has 1 row, project-table has 1 row, join-table has 1 row

$secondProject = new Project();
$secondProject->addUser($user);

$em->persist($secondProject);
$em->flush();

// user-table has 1 row, project-table has 2 rows, join-table has 2 rows

$user->removeProject($project);

$em->flush();

// user-table has 1 row, project-table has 2 rows, join-table has 1 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

The relation is an `ArrayCollection`, you'll want to `add` your object to this collection.
Something like the following:

```
$project = new Project;
$project->title = 'Foo';

// Create new user
$user = new User;
$user->name = 'Bar';
$user->getProjects()->add($project);
$em->persist($user);

// ..or add to existing user
$existingUser = $userRepo->findById(1);
$existingUser->getProjects()->add($project);
$em->persist($existingUser);

$project->getUsers()->add($user);

$em->persist($project);
$em->flush();
```